# Android custom checkbox up text

Tags: android

I am currently using this example to create a custom checkbox:
http://www.hrupin.com/2011/09/how-to-make-android-checkbox-and-radiobutton-custom-style

But the image I am using for my checkbox is currently covering part of my text. Is there a way to design the checkbox or selector to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting margins or padding?

Comment: Would that be consistant between devices? That is my biggest worry?

Comment: As long as you set them with the unit dp instead of sp; ie: 5dp it should be as they are device independent. See: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension for more info on pixel units.